# emacs c c++ reference document

Tags: c++, emacs

I am using emacs as C , C++ ide.

I want to configure emacs so I can read C and C++ APIs (reference library) inside emacs.

Please let em know how to do it.

BT

Comment: `M-x man` `RET` `[section number] function name` works for C functions whose man pages are installed in standard locations, such as `scanf` and `gets`.  Are you looking for something else?  Perhaps on a non Unix system?

Answer (score 5):

Check out the following link, it contains man-pages based on the www.cppreference.com offline archive:
https://github.com/jeaye/stdman

After installing, you could use: **man std::string** or whatever and view the cpp reference directly.

There are also other offline reference formats available here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: My answer is completely dependant on the link. You can't possibly install the man pages without going to the GitHub link above. Also, if some part of the installation process is updated, I shouldn't have to update this answer. Thanks for the feedback in any case.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. This GitHub project installs WAY more than the standard packages do.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following line in my *.emacs* file to automatically show a man page for the c function under the cursor when I push F1 (of course it assumes you have the development man pages installed):

```
(global-set-key  [f1] (lambda () (interactive) (manual-entry (current-word))))
```

For example on an Ubuntu linux system, the `manpages-dev` and `libstdc++6-4.4-doc` packages contain manpages for the C and C++ standard libraries, respectively. Similar packages exist for other systems, including MacOSX

Answer (score 3):

`M-x man` should work on Linux systems for reading the man pages that are installed in standard locations.

If you install the stl-manual for C++, they come in HTML.  You could use `M-x w3m-browse-url` and pass it the `file:///path/to/index.html` if you want to read the stl-manuals from inside Emacs.

The info pages explain in detail.  `M-x info`, `m emacs`, `m man page`.

Answer (score 1):

[CClookup](https://github.com/tsgates/cclookup) will do precisely what you want.

Comment: The link is dead.  Any mirrors?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code into your emacs config file. this code will add key binding `[C-h d]` to c-mode and c++-mode.

```lisp
(dolist (hook
         '(c-mode-hook
           c++-mode-hook))
  (add-hook hook
            (lambda ()
              (local-set-key (kbd "C-h d") 'manual-entry))))
```

Comment: remove the current word call. It makes it more prone to error. Let manual entry figure out word at point.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem as you have
and I find an emacs extension for the function 
which help myself to check the cpp document. 
its name of the extension is cppref,
this is the github address for this package:
https://github.com/realfirst/cppref

you can bind a key (e.g. F1) to the function
or invoke it via M + cppref. Wish you enjoy 
it.

Comment: The answers above are fantastic, I had no idea on stdman/cppref as man pages.  I do have a problem with c++ namespace qualifiers not working at all when I do a binding through current-word in emacs.   Any help there?  eg std::string is where my cursor is, but the binding picks up either std or string and not as one word hence the documentation is not found.  I can do it wimanually using M-x commands interestingly.